# Unbound value "string_of_sexp"

Tags: ocaml, s-expression

It works quite well in utop with #require "ppx_jane" but
I added `(preprocess (pps ppx_jane))` in my dune file which looks like this:

```
(library
 (preprocess (pps ppx_jane))
 (name raftml)
 (modules raft rpc types)
 (libraries 
   core 
   core_unix 
   proto 
   grpc 
   grpc-lwt 
   ocaml-protoc 
   lwt 
   lwt.unix 
   h2 
   h2-lwt-unix 
   domainslib
   yojson
   ppx_jane
   ppx_sexp_conv
   ppx_deriving_yojson
   ppx_deriving
   ppx_deriving_yojson.runtime))
```

And my types are like this:

```
type log = {
    mutable command: string;
    mutable term: int32;
    mutable index: int32
} [@@deriving sexp]
```

I call `sexp_of_log` in my code like this:

```
let persist () = Out_channel.write_all "file_name" ~data:(Sexp.to_string (sexp_of_log { command = "hello"; term = (10l); index = (24l); }))
```

And there's an error when I run `dune build`: Unbound value "string_of_sexp"

Comment: What happens if you add `sexplib` to your libraries in dune?

Comment: @Chris the problem remains.

Comment: Have you shown us all of your code? I don't see a call to `string_of_sexp` in what you've shown.

Comment: @Chris Yes. string is the type of command which is a field of log.

Comment: You might as well just get rid of those parens. Thy aren't doing anything other than making your source code 4 bytes larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding:

```ml
open Sexplib.Std
```

At the top of the file that has the record types deriving `sexp`.

Comment: Alternatively, fully qualify the call to `string_of_sexp` or open the module locally.